# onclick playSound Method not working in intel xdk

Tags: audio, onclick, intel

i am not able to play the audio file onclick of a button.

here is the code i got from the xdk website.

```
function audioBtn()
     {
      // play the sound
      intel.xdk.player.playSound("sounds/anything.wav");
      }
```

the audio location is:

C:\Users\abc\Documents\pqr\www\sounds\anything.wav

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Intel XDK Emulator doesn't support playing audio files using the intel.xdk Player object, but this does work within the Intel App Preview mobile app for testing by scanning the QR Code under the Test tab.

For example, you can play audio files (supported by your platform of course) within your application in App Preview or on device as follows

```
intel.xdk.player.playSound(intel.xdk.webRoot + "sounds/anything.wav");
```

intel.xdk.webroot contains the path for the www/ directory.